Faithfulness between representation and KG-module
I was studying representation theory when a question came to my mind.
Let's consider a representation of a group G into a K-vector space V and the associated KG-module structure on V. It's easy to see that, if the KG-module is faithful, then the representation itself is faithful. I'm having troubles in proving the converse. Is it true?
In other words, in the situation above, is it true that if a representation on a K-space is faithful, then the associated KG-module is faithful? And, if so, how can one prove it?

No that's not true. Take for example the cyclic group of order $2$ acting on $K$ by $\pm 1$.  This is a faithful action of the group, but the element $1 + x$ (where $x$ is the non-identity element) in the group algebra acts by $0$ so it is not a faithful $kG$-module.

Thank you very much.

Any intuition on how this cannot be true?

I mean faithfulness means roughly "no two elements act the same way" and there is just way more stuff in $kG$ than in $G$ itself, so it should be harder for everything in $kG$ to act differently than for everything in $G$ to act differently.

Seems legit, that was my general idea too. But I also supposed that, being G a k-basis for kG, the faithfulness of G could imply the other. And still it isn't.
